# How to share network images and pdf to other apps in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Instead of asset image I want share network image

```
void share(){
  final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('lib/images/image.png');

  await Share.file('test', 'test',bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png');
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this package [wc_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/wc_flutter_share)

Example:

```dart
http.Response response = await http.get(
    'https://flutter.io/images/flutter-mark-square-100.png',
);   

await WcFlutterShare.share(  
    sharePopupTitle: 'share',  
    subject: 'This is subject',  
    text: 'This is text',  
    fileName: 'share.png',  
    mimeType: 'image/png',  
    bytesOfFile: response.bodyBytes,
);
```

Comment: I tried this package but there is no method to share network images and pdf .

Comment: I change it, and you should use response.bodyBytes